# jaxb not compiling niem schema

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<schema                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0"
    xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0"

    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com"
>

    <import namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" schemaLocation="./niem/structures/2.0/structures.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" schemaLocation="./niem/niem-core/2.0/niem-core.xsd"/>

    <complexType name="TestType">
            <complexContent>
            <extension base="s:ComplexObjectType">
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

```
     [java] Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
     [java] No element mapping exists for "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0":"Augmentation"
     [java]     this problem is related to the following location:
     [java]         at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl(scope=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl$GLOBAL, substitutionHeadName=Augmentation, defaultValue=^@, substitutionHeadNamespace=http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0, namespace=http://niem.gov/niem/ansi-nist/2.0, name=ProtectionOrderAugmentation)
     [java]         at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ObjectFactory.createProtectionOrderAugmentation(gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ProtectionOrderAugmentationType)
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ObjectFactory
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPalmImagePositionType.palmPosition
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPalmImagePositionType
     [java]         at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MajorCasePrintSegmentOffsetType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintImageNISTQualityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintImageQualityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintImageMajorCasePrintType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPalmImagePositionType])
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FingerprintSetType.fingerprint
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FingerprintSetType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonType.personFingerprintSet
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactInformationType.contactResponder
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactInformationType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocationType.locationContactInformation
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocationType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ImageType.imageLocation
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ImageType
     [java]         at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObjectFactory.createImage(gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ImageType)
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObjectFactory
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ToothType.toothPosition
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ToothType
     [java]         at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class com.test.TestType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ToothType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.EntityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.BiometricType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.IdentificationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocaleType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.OrganizationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObligationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DNALocusType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PropertyType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.RelativeLocationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonNameType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObligationExemptionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MeasureRangeValueType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FacilityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemValueType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.TelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AddressType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MapLocationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.TwoDimensionalGeographicCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonLanguageType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactInformationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PassportType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LatitudeCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MedicalConditionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DocumentType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.SupervisionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InjuryType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.HighwayType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InternationalTelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemTitleType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DNAType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.JurisdictionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LesseeType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ScheduleDayType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ClothingType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CapabilityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.WeaponType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.IntoxicationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AddressGridType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.EncounterClassificationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LienType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DateRangeType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.UTMCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LongitudeCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.VehicleBranderType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AreaType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DrivingRestrictionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DecalType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LessorType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CaseDispositionDecisionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.EmailType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.StreetType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FingerprintSetType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemRegistrationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PhysicalFeatureType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CircularRegionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.NANPTelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InsuranceType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.StatusType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FullTelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactRadioType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DispositionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MeasureType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.StructuredAddressType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.KitType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MilitarySummaryType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LienHolderType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AngularMeasureType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.VehicleBrandType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InstantMessengerType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DriverLicenseBaseType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CrossStreetType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ActivityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AssociationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.IdentityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ImageQualityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.SignatureImageVectorType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PhysicalFeatureSizeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FaceImageAttributeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PhysicalFeatureColorDetailType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.OrganizationDocumentCountType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionCharacterSetDirectoryType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.SignatureImageVectorRepresentationType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionImageResolutionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPatternType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.NISTStandardMinutiaeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FaceImageFeaturePointType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PhysicalFeatureDescriptionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeReadingSystemType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeFingerPositionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ImageCaptureType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeFingerPatternType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.BinaryType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ContentRecordType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaPositionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionContentSummaryType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionDomainType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.RecordType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PoseAngleType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.IdentificationRangeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintType])
     [java]         at com.test.TestType
     [java]         at public com.test.TestType com.test.ObjectFactory.createTestType()
     [java]         at com.test.ObjectFactory
     [java] No element mapping exists for "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0":"Augmentation"
     [java]     this problem is related to the following location:
     [java]         at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl(scope=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl$GLOBAL, substitutionHeadName=Augmentation, defaultValue=^@, substitutionHeadNamespace=http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0, namespace=http://niem.gov/niem/ansi-nist/2.0, name=ActivityAugmentation)
     [java]         at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ObjectFactory.createActivityAugmentation(gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ActivityAugmentationType)
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ObjectFactory
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPalmImagePositionType.palmPosition
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPalmImagePositionType
     [java]         at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MajorCasePrintSegmentOffsetType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintImageNISTQualityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintImageQualityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintImageMajorCasePrintType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPalmImagePositionType])
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FingerprintSetType.fingerprint
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FingerprintSetType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonType.personFingerprintSet
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactInformationType.contactResponder
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactInformationType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocationType.locationContactInformation
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocationType
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ImageType.imageLocation
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ImageType
     [java]         at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObjectFactory.createImage(gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ImageType)
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObjectFactory
     [java]         at protected java.util.List gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ToothType.toothPosition
     [java]         at gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ToothType
     [java]         at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class com.test.TestType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ToothType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.EntityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.BiometricType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.IdentificationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LocaleType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.OrganizationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObligationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DNALocusType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PropertyType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.RelativeLocationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonNameType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ObligationExemptionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MeasureRangeValueType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FacilityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemValueType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.TelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AddressType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MapLocationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.TwoDimensionalGeographicCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonLanguageType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactInformationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PersonType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PassportType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LatitudeCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MedicalConditionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DocumentType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.SupervisionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InjuryType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.HighwayType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InternationalTelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemTitleType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DNAType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.JurisdictionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LesseeType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ScheduleDayType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ClothingType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CapabilityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.WeaponType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.IntoxicationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AddressGridType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.EncounterClassificationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LienType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DateRangeType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.UTMCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LongitudeCoordinateType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.VehicleBranderType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AreaType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DrivingRestrictionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DecalType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LessorType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CaseDispositionDecisionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.EmailType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.StreetType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FingerprintSetType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemRegistrationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.PhysicalFeatureType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CircularRegionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.NANPTelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InsuranceType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.StatusType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.FullTelephoneNumberType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ContactRadioType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DispositionType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MeasureType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.StructuredAddressType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.KitType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.MilitarySummaryType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.LienHolderType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AngularMeasureType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.VehicleBrandType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.InstantMessengerType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.DriverLicenseBaseType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.CrossStreetType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ActivityType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.ItemType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.AssociationType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.IdentityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ImageQualityType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.SignatureImageVectorType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PhysicalFeatureSizeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FaceImageAttributeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PhysicalFeatureColorDetailType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.OrganizationDocumentCountType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionCharacterSetDirectoryType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.SignatureImageVectorRepresentationType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionImageResolutionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintPatternType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.NISTStandardMinutiaeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FaceImageFeaturePointType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PhysicalFeatureDescriptionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeReadingSystemType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeFingerPositionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ImageCaptureType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaeFingerPatternType, class gov.niem.niem.niem_core._2.BinaryType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.ContentRecordType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.MinutiaPositionType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionContentSummaryType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.TransactionDomainType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.RecordType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.PoseAngleType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.IdentificationRangeType, class gov.niem.niem.ansi_nist._2.FingerprintType])
     [java]         at com.test.TestType
     [java]         at public com.test.TestType com.test.ObjectFactory.createTestType()
     [java]         at com.test.ObjectFactory
```

I've for days now, trying to figure out what the cause is. `Augmentation` and `AugmentationType` are declared in `./niem/niem-core/2.0/niem-core.xsd`

The niem xsd files are found here:

- https://www.niem.gov/create-iepd/pages/production-releases.aspx
- http://release.niem.gov/niem/2.1/niem-2.1.zip

My `Test.java` file fails on this:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.test");
```

I've tried using the JDK6 built in jaxb implementation and overriding it with the latest jaxb implementation found on java.net (and putting the api jar in jre/lib/endorsed).

I've found [this old forum message from 2007](http://www.java.net/node/664721?force=502), with a similar error.
You have to do a browser-view-source to see the xml bits in that thread.
I've tried all kinds of variations on this, adjusting it to what the niem schemas look like now, but I can't make any sense of it.

Is this a bug in the jaxb xjc compiler or a bug in the niem schema files? Apparently, it compiles with XMLSpy, but I want to stick with xjc/jaxb if possible...

I'm compiling the xml files like this:

```
xjc -d src/java -b bindings.xml src/jaxb/test.xsd
```

`bindings.xml`:

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.0"
>
    <jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord">
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue unmarshalling ECF-4.0 messages (based on NIEM).  I solved it by explicitly constructing my JAXBContext from the ObjectFactory classes instead of the package names:

```
ecf4Context = JAXBContext.newInstance(gov.niem.niem.structures._2.ObjectFactory.class,
      oasis.names.tc.legalxml_courtfiling.schema.xsd.corefilingmessage_4.ObjectFactory.class);
```

Once I made that change, I was quickly able to pull complex messages into Java.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use JDK 1.6 update 16 instead of 24.  I don't know what the cause is, but that fixed it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all the concerned classes or object factories as comma separated parameters in JAXBContext.newInstance()